# Difference in import_role and include_role in terms of variable precedence

Tags: ansible

I have defined a variable `var_for_all` in `group_vars/all.yml` and another one `variables_role_var1` in `roles/../vars/main.yml`. Overriding them in playbook using `import_role` and `include_role` seems to follow different precedence rules and results different values.

I was under the assumption that first role block will output below debug message:

```
"msg": "var_for_all = From group_vars/all.yml, variables_role_var1 = from role vars/ dir"
```

But getting output as:

```
"msg": "var_for_all = From playbook import_role_test2, variables_role_var1 = from role vars/ dir"
```

Could anyone please explain the behavior or point me if I am missing something?
Have gone thorough [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable), [Dynamic vs Static](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#dynamic-vs-static) and [Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#playbooks-reuse-roles).

my_playbook.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: import_role_test1
      import_role:
        name: variables
        tasks_from: precedence

    - name: import_role_test2
      import_role:
        name: variables
        tasks_from: precedence
      vars: 
        var_for_all: From playbook import_role_test2
        variables_role_var1: From playbook import_role_test2

    - name: include_role_test3
      include_role:
        name: variables
        tasks_from: precedence
      vars: 
        var_for_all: From playbook import_role_test3
        variables_role_var1: From playbook import_role_test3
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce the results. See the code and results below the line.

- The result of test 3 can be explained by [precedence 17.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) of *"task vars (only for the task)"*.
- The result of test 2 can be explained also by precedence 17. of *"task vars (only for the task)"*.
- The result of *"variables_role_var1"* in test 1 can be explained by precedence 15. of *"role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)"*. I can't explain the result of *"var_for_all"* in test 1. This might be an Ansible's issue. Both 1st and 2nd test import the role and *"Ansible pre-processes all static imports during Playbook parsing time."*

---

```
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml 
var_for_all: From group_vars/all.yml

shell> cat roles/variables/vars/main.yml
variables_role_var1: From roles/variables/vars/main.yml

shell> cat roles/variables/tasks/precedence.yml 
- debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ var_for_all }}"
      - "{{ variables_role_var1 }}"

shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: import_role_test1
      import_role:
        name: variables
        tasks_from: precedence.yml

    - name: import_role_test2
      import_role:
        name: variables
        tasks_from: precedence.yml
      vars: 
        var_for_all: From playbook import_role_test2
        variables_role_var1: From playbook import_role_test2

    - name: include_role_test3
      include_role:
        name: variables
        tasks_from: precedence.yml
      vars: 
        var_for_all: From playbook import_role_test3
        variables_role_var1: From playbook import_role_test3
```

give

```
    "msg": [
        "From playbook import_role_test2",
        "From roles/variables/vars/main.yml"
    ]

    "msg": [
        "From playbook import_role_test2",
        "From playbook import_role_test2"
    ]

    "msg": [
        "From playbook import_role_test3",
        "From playbook import_role_test3"
    ]
```

---

Things may change when the variables are explicitly expanded by a host

```
shell> cat roles/variables/tasks/precedence.yml 
- set_fact:
    var_for_all: "{{ var_for_all }}"
    variables_role_var1: "{{ variables_role_var1 }}"
- debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ var_for_all }}"
      - "{{ variables_role_var1 }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": [
        "From playbook import_role_test2",
        "From roles/variables/vars/main.yml"
    ]

    "msg": [
        "From playbook import_role_test2",
        "From roles/variables/vars/main.yml"
    ]

    "msg": [
        "From playbook import_role_test3",
        "From playbook import_role_test3"
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks. You got the exact result that I am getting.

Comment: There are issues, I think.

Comment: For information, [found this open issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50278). Apparently, it's not been decided whether it's a bug or just missing documentation.

Comment: It's a bug, I think. It's not acceptable the value of variable changes when evaluated, e.g. `var_for_all: "{{ var_for_all }}"`. See updated test2. There is [more](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/projects/19).

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is quite simpler:

All `import_*` statement run at initialization time and any kind of `vars`(*) will be initialized also, whether it has a failing condition or anything that skipping the real execution.

*(*) e.g.: `vars/main.yml` file from the imported task or the `vars` attribute of the `import_role`*

- A quite minimal example:

  ```yml
  - debug:
      var: foo

  - when: False
    import_role:
      name: any_role
    vars:
      foo: 'Cherry'
  ```
- And the result:

  ```
  TASK [fun : debug] ******************************************************************
  task path: roles/fun/tasks/main.yml:1
  ok: [test.local] => {
      "foo": "Cherry"
  }
  ```

(That was the reason why I replaced the my all `import_role` to `include_role`)